# Monitor percentage of CPU and memory in GKE nodes

Tags: monitoring, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I would like to use Stackdriver monitoring to watch for my GKE nodes' CPU/mem % usage.

However, when going through the Stackdriver Monitoring UI, there does not seem to be any such option available (meaning in terms of percentage).

On the other hand there seem to be for example 2 extremely similar metrics (their description is **identical**) for (what appears to be) absolute mem usage. (screenshots attached).

Is anyone aware how one can provide for percentage of memory and CPU used on GKE nodes? (not containers)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

per https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes :

`node/memory/allocatable_utilization` and `node/cpu/allocatable_utilization` 
seem to be doing what you want:

- `node/memory/allocatable_utilization` - [BETA] Memory allocatable utilization

  - Description: The fraction of the allocatable memory that is currently in use on the instance. This value cannot exceed 1 as usage cannot exceed allocatable memory bytes. Sampled every 60 seconds. After sampling, data is not visible for up to 120 seconds.
  - Kind: GAUGE, Type: DOUBLE, Unit: 1
  - Monitored resource: k8s_node
  - Labels:

    - **memory_type**: Either `evictable` or `non-evictable`. Evictable memory is memory that can be easily reclaimed by the kernel, while non-evictable memory cannot.
    - **component**: Name of the respective system daemon.
- `node/cpu/allocatable_utilization` - [BETA] CPU allocatable utilization.

  - Description: The fraction of the allocatable CPU that is currently in use on the instance. Sampled every 60 seconds. After sampling, data is not visible for up to 240 seconds.
  - Kind: GAUGE, Type: DOUBLE, Unit: 1
  - Monitored resource: k8s_node

*Both metrics are marked as `BETA`, though.*

---

original answer mentioned: `container/cpu/limit_utilization` and `container/memory/limit_utilization`

Comment: Aren't these metrics measuring CPU and memory for containers instead of nodes?

Comment: Good point, for node you probably want to use `node/memory/allocatable_utilization ` and `node/cpu/allocatable_utilization `

Comment: I would updated the initial answer since question is asking about `nodes` metrics not `containers`.

Comment: Any ways to get percentage utilization for cpu and memory?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not possible. Please have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes) page where you can find list of metrics that can be collected from Google Kubernetes Engine and then used with Stackdriver Monitoring. In addition you can also check [these document](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp) to find some extra information about available metrics.

Meanwhile, you can find utilization at `Kubernetes Engine` -> `Clusters` -> `Cluster` -> `Nodes` -> `Node details` or just use a command line:

```
kubectl top nodes                                            
NAME                                       CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
gke-test-cluster-default-pool-cd22e088-29sd   45m          4%     647Mi           24%       
gke-test-cluster-default-pool-cd22e088-8xsg   93m          9%     693Mi           26%       
gke-test-cluster-default-pool-cd22e088-t1h0   41m          4%     625Mi           23%
```

Also, you can solve this problem by using other 3rd party monitoring solutions.